# vectors - normal and tangential vectors

Tags: vectors

Let $x$ is a point on a surface $S$, we can write a vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ at $x$. We can write $\boldsymbol{v}$ as

$$
\boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v}_{||} + \boldsymbol{v}_{\perp}
$$
Where the first and second terms on the RHS are the tangential and normal vectors.

The normal vector is
$$
\boldsymbol{v}_{\perp} = (\boldsymbol{v}\cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}
$$

where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal to the surface. My question is, if this normal vector is zero and ALL of the components of the unit normal vector $\hat{n}$ are non-zero, then does this guarantee that $\boldsymbol{v}=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Consider the vector $n=\frac{1}{\sqrt6}(1,1,-2)$. Then the vector $v=(1,1,1)$ satisfies $v\cdot n=0$ but $v\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes. I just realized I asked something stupid.

Comment: @David That's fantastic. You have obtained the answer but your own. What else could you want?